# How to retain cookies in node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I wish to create an application using [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) which does the simple job to open a remote web application. The web application has some cookie based authentication. Considering that the user has signed-in successfully, how can the required cookies be retained, so that the next time the application runs, the user will be authenticated?

Comment: Also stuck in the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2018, NW.js retains cookies and other persistent browser data by default. These are stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%/name-in-manifest/` in Windows or equivalent depending on OS. Nothing is required from the application itself, you do not have to persist cookie data manually in local storage.

Comment: I facing the same issue of session not storing with latest NWJS 0.52.0 release as well, I'm also providing the following parameter `--user-data-dir='/Users/sunil/sunil/temp/userdatadir/profile1'` in `chromium-args`. Any idea why it is not storing the session, or what can be the problem? Also, created a question. I'll be thankful if you can provide your guidance - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68427188/819866

Answer (score 9):

1. You can get auth cookies using this instructions:
   https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/window#windowcookies
2. Save it with prefered method:
   https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app
3. On next start just check that record exists, and set cookies with method from 1.

Should be something like this:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

function login() {
   var opts = {};
   if(localStorage.auth) {
      opts.cookies: [
           'Auth': localStorage.auth
      ];
   }

    someRequest.get(opts, function(result) {
        if(result)
          localStorage.auth = win.cookies.get('auth');
    });
}
```